# The n-torsion subgroup $E[n]$ is isomorphic to $Z_n$ x $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

In Washington's "Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography",

the proof that $E[n] \simeq Z_n$ x $Z_n$ is concluded by referring to the structure theorem of finite abelian groups ($E[n] \simeq Z_{n_1} $ x $...$ x $Z_{n_k}$ with $n_i | n_{i+1}$).

If we have a prime $l$ with $l | n_i$ for all i, why can we conclude that "$E[l] \subseteq E[n]$ has order $l^2$"?
The proof continues with "Multiplication by n annihilates $E[n] \simeq Z_{n_1}$ x $Z_{n_2}$, so we must have $n_2 | n$". Why is that the case?

The conclusion step that $n_1 = n_2$ is clear but I still can't see why the condition that the characteristic $p$ of the field does not divide $n$ is necessary.

Comment: For the first part, hasn't he shown previously that the claim holds whenever $n$ is a prime different from the characteristic? The second part is from the fact that the number annihilating $Z_{n_2}$ precisely are those that are multiples of $n_2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In the first part he has shown that it needs to have order $l^2$, but not that $E[l] \subseteq E[n]$ (we only know that $l | n_i$ for all $i$). Could you maybe elaborate the second part further? I still can't seem to understand :( Maybe I don't understand the term annihilation...

Comment: But if $l\mid n$ then $E[l]\subseteq E[n]$ by definition.

Comment: In the proof when $E[l] \subseteq E[n]$ is stated, we have not yet showed any relation between $n_i$ and $n$... we only know $l | n_i$.

Comment: But we also know that all the $n_i$ divide $n$, since this is the $n$-torsion part.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look again into that.